# Dissolve of polygons leaving internal lines

Tags: qgis, polygon, dissolve, outline

I have been trying to produce an outline of a stylised island using dissolve however there are internal "lines" that remain after I use dissolve?
The hexagons that are being merged were created with the grid function so there shouldn't be any gaps present between them. I have tried "delete holes" however QGIS does recognise the lines as holes. QGIS is also showing the output as one large polygon too.

I'm a bit stumped as to why this is occurring. Alternatively is there is a different way to easily produce the outline of the polygons?

The below photos show the grid created input and the dissolve output with lines on it.

[image: Input grid]

[image: Dissolve tool output showing lines]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the polygons are not contiguous (there are gaps between them). To solve the problem, you can you use Clean tool located under GRASS tools, which has the a clean tool `Snap`. You need to run QGIS with GRASS enabled.

Search for Clean tool in toolbox and open it:

[image]

Select the polygon layer that you want to clean, then go to the clean tools and click on the `...` 3 dots.

[image]

Select Snap option

[image]

You may need to adjust the snapping tolerance in order to get the desired output.

Answer (score 2):

Another quick solution could be to buffer the polygons by a very small amount such that it eliminates the overlap.
this will obviously only be an applicable solution if accuracy of the buffer amount is not an issue for you.

I have sometimes done this approach, instead of using snapping, mainly because of performance but also if the source data has inherent errors, which causes the snapping to fail. i was spending far too much time trying to correct data errors, when in the end a simple buffer not only solved the data errors, but also resulted in nice overlap for a dissolve to work.